# /bin/bash -c stopping counting with date

Tags: linux, bash, shell

/bin/bash -c not starting counting with date:

```
/bin/bash -c "while true; do echo [`date +'%F%t%T%t%Z'`] Keep Alive; sleep 1; done"
```

The output is:

```
[2015-07-06 13:44:36 UTC] Keep Alive
[2015-07-06 13:44:36 UTC] Keep Alive
[2015-07-06 13:44:36 UTC] Keep Alive
[2015-07-06 13:44:36 UTC] Keep Alive
[2015-07-06 13:44:36 UTC] Keep Alive
```

Why not working if I try to run with `/bin/bash -c`?
The upper example line is part of a bigger systemd script, which is starting a Docker container. It's part of this line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name lanti-debian --hostname lanti-debian --user debuser --volume /home/core/share:/media/share:rw -p 8080:80 -p 8081:22 lanti-debian-li /bin/bash -c "while true; do echo [`date +'%F%t%T%t%Z'`] Keep Alive; sleep 1; done"
```

This line will keeping alive my Debian docker container. I need the timestamp for debugging when I inspecting with fleetctl journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the command `date` is expanded (and hence executed) only once, i.e., when you invoke `/bin/bash -c` or the other `run` command.

All you have to do is quote the script so that the `date` command is executed at every iteration. Double quotes `"` will expand the command, single quotes `'` will not:

```
/bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo [`date +%F%t%T%t%Z`] Keep Alive; sleep 1; done'
```

Comment: Thank You! It's working now. I didn't know that shell script quotes are case-sensitive. So probably best practice to use outside single quote and inside double, for example: `$ /bin/bash -c 'echo -e "Now sleeping 5 seconds" && sleep 5'`?